# Dataframe.map need to result with more than the rows in dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am using scala and spark and have a simple dataframe.map to produce the required transformation on data. However I need to provide an additional  row of data with the modified original. How can I use the dataframe.map to give out this.

ex:
dataset from:

- id, name, age
- 1, john, 23
- 2, peter, 32

if age < 25 default to 25.

dataset to:

- id, name, age
- 1, john, 25
- 1, john, -23
- 2, peter, 32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would a 'UnionAll' handle it?

eg.

```
   df1 = original dataframe
   df2 = transformed df1

   df1.unionAll(df2)
```

**EDIT**: implementation using unionAll()

```
val df1=sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(  (1,"john",23) , (2,"peter",32) )).
           toDF( "id","name","age")

def udfTransform= udf[Int,Int] { (age) => if (age<25) 25 else age }

val df2=df1.withColumn("age2", udfTransform($"age")).
            where("age!=age2").
            drop("age2")

df1.withColumn("age", udfTransform($"age")).
    unionAll(df2).
    orderBy("id").
    show()

+---+-----+---+
| id| name|age|
+---+-----+---+
|  1| john| 25|
|  1| john| 23|
|  2|peter| 32|
+---+-----+---+
```

Note: the implementation differs a bit from the originally proposed (naive) solution. The devil is always in the detail!

**EDIT 2**: implementation using nested array and explode

```
val df1=sx.createDataFrame(Seq(  (1,"john",23) , (2,"peter",32) )).
           toDF( "id","name","age")
def udfArr= udf[Array[Int],Int] { (age) => 
               if (age<25) Array(age,25) else Array(age) }

val df2=df1.withColumn("age", udfArr($"age"))

df2.show()
+---+-----+--------+
| id| name|     age|
+---+-----+--------+
|  1| john|[23, 25]|
|  2|peter|    [32]|
+---+-----+--------+


df2.withColumn("age",explode($"age") ).show()
+---+-----+---+
| id| name|age|
+---+-----+---+
|  1| john| 23|
|  1| john| 25|
|  2|peter| 32|
+---+-----+---+
```

Comment: may I ask how does your answer solves the question ?

Comment: See implementation 1 and 2 added to above.

Comment: Seems second option might work for me, will try it out and update. Thanks.

Comment: If it works for you, may I suggest you update the status of this answer to 'accepted' ?